# Auto capture webcam without button

Tags: javascript

I am trying to make webcam capture image when someone login using barcode, usually to capture with webcam using button `onClick="take_snapshot()"`. How to set webcam capture image without `onClick` button. For example when someone try to login, webcam will automatically capture, JavaScript function `take_snapshot();` will capture and save image to path. I have put `"take_snapshot()"` on body `Onload="take_snapshot()"`, but it is not working. I get `"Webcam.js Error: Webcam is not loaded yet"`

Below my code

```
<div id = "result"></div>
        <form action="index.php" method="POST">
            <div class = "form-group">
                <center>    
                <label>SCAN ID CARD BARCODE</label>
                <h1>
                <span class = "glyphicon glyphicon-barcode">
                </span>
                </h1>
                </center>

                <input type = "text" name="idkar" class = "form-control" autofocus required/>
                <br /><center>


                <?php
                include('login.php');
                ?>

                <script type="text/javascript">
                if(location.search.indexOf('r') < 0){
                var hash = window.location.hash;
                var loc = window.location.href.replace(hash, '');
                loc += (loc.indexOf('?') < 0? '?' : '&') + 'r';
                setTimeout(function(){window.location.href = loc + hash;}, 5000);
                }
                </script>



                <br /></center>
                <input type = "submit" name="search" value="ENTER" class = "btn btn-primary btn-block">
                <span class = "glyphicon glyphicon-login"></span>
    </div>
    </div>
    <div class = "col-lg-0" ></div>
    <div class = "col-lg-3 well">
    <center>

    <div id="my_camera"></div>
    <!-- First, include the Webcam.js JavaScript Library -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../webcam.min.js"></script>
    <!-- Configure a few settings and attach camera -->
    <script language="JavaScript">
        Webcam.set({
        // live preview size
        width: 240,
        height: 200,
        // device capture size
        dest_width: 240,
        dest_height: 170,
        // final cropped size
        crop_width: 240,
        crop_height: 168,
        // format and quality
        image_format: 'jpeg',
        jpeg_quality: 100
        });
        Webcam.attach( '#my_camera' );
    </script>
    <!-- A button for taking snaps -->
    <input type=button value="Take Snapshot" onClick="take_snapshot()">
    <br></br>
    <!-- Code to handle taking the snapshot and displaying it locally -->
    <script language="JavaScript">
    function take_snapshot() {
    // take snapshot and get image data
    Webcam.snap( function(data_uri) {
    // display results in page
    document.getElementById('results').innerHTML = 
    '<img src="'+data_uri+'"/>';
    } );}
    </script>
    <div id="results">Your captured image will appear here...</div>
</form> 
</div>
```

I want to capture webcam image before login.php or on login.php

Where should I put the `"take_snapshot();`?

Comment: what has this to do with PHP?

Comment: @treyBake `<?php
                        include('login.php');
                        ?>` :p

Comment: that one line doesn't mean it's related to PHP. It just happens to have php code in your JS-related issues

Comment: @treyBake - not **my** issues :p (I agree with you though)

Comment: look at the [events demo](https://github.com/jhuckaby/webcamjs/blob/master/demos/events.html) for webcamjs ... you'll want on('load' or on('live'

Comment: my question is where im put take_snapshot()? i want after scan barcode login.php will run and webcam is capture at the same time